# При сравнении строк с помощью strcmp() и strcasecmp(), строки сравниваются не полностью

Tags: c, сравнение, hashmap

Имеется хэш-таблица в которую были внесены слова из словаря. Слова в таблице в нижнем регистре.

```
typedef struct node
{
    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    struct node *next;
}
node;

// Hash table
node *table[N];
```

Функция должна находить заданное слово в словаре, игнорируя регистр и возвращать **bool**.

```
bool check(const char *word)
{
    // TODO
    int box = hash(word);

    char fin[strlen(word)];
    bool search = false;
    for (node *find = table[box]; find != NULL; find = find -> next)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++)
        {
            if (word[i] >= 65 && word[i] <= 90)
            {
                fin[i] = word[i] + 32;
            }
            else
            {
                fin[i] = word[i];
            }
        }
        if (strcmp(fin, find->word))
        {
            search = true;
        }
    }
    return search;
}
```

По хэш-коду слова получаем доступ к началу нужного нам связного списка и сравниваем каждое слово.
Проблема в том, что функция **strcmp()** сравнивает не всю строку целиком, а только первые три символа.
То есть на пример слово **table** будет равно слову **tablet**.
В начале пробовал с функцией **strcasecmp()** без преобразования строки в нижний регистр, но та же беда.
В чём может быть причина и как это исправить?

Вот еще один вариант с той же проблемой

```
bool check(const char *word) 
{ 
// TODO 
int box = hash(word); 
char fin[strlen(word)]; 
bool search = false; 
for (node *find = table[box]; find != NULL; find = find -> next) 
     { 
          if (strcasecmp(find->word, word)) 
          { 
               search = true; 
          } 
     } 
return search;
}
```

```
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    // TODO
    FILE *inptr = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (inptr == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    int temp;
    char tempword[LENGTH];
    //
    int di = 0;
    while (fscanf(inptr, "%s", tempword) != EOF)
    {
        node *element = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (element == NULL)
        {
            fclose(inptr);
            return false;
        }
        element -> next = NULL;
        strcpy(element -> word, tempword); //Пропущенная строка.
        temp = hash(tempword);
        if (&(*table[temp]) == NULL)
        {
            table[temp] = element;
        }
        else
        {
            element -> next = table[temp];
            table[temp] = element;
        }
        di++;
    }
    fclose(inptr);
    return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: В функции `load()` вы теряете все почитанные `tempword[]` (не копируете их в элементы хэш-таблицы)

Comment: Пардон, строку пропустил. Слово в таблицу вносил с помощью функции **strcpy()**.

Answer (score 0):

У вас `strcmp` не находит финальный ноль в строке `fin`, (потому что он там должен быть, а вы его туда не записываете), и поэтому творится непонятно что.

```
 {
        ........
            fin[i] = word[i];
        }
    }
    fin[i]='\0';  //вот этого не хватает
    if (strcmp(fin, find->word))
    {
```

*P.S Ваша программа претендует на вторую премию [Шлемиель-2021](https://nudenoizer.livejournal.com/43431.html). Перавую, увы, забрали ребята, [которые напихали strlen в парсер json](https://habr.com/ru/company/itsumma/blog/544830/).*

Бонус: вот этот агрегат:

```
for (int i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++)
    {
        if (word[i] >= 65 && word[i] <= 90)
        {
            fin[i] = word[i] + 32;
        }
        else
        {
            fin[i] = word[i];
        }
    }
```

можно переделать вот так:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(word); i++)
{
    word[i]|=0x20; //не зря строчные и 
                   //заглавные буквы отличаются одним битом
}
```

Comment: Возможно я не корректно преобразовал строку, но та же проблема остается, если строку не преобразовывать в нижний регистр и воспользоваться функцией **strcasecmp()** с таким кодом: ```        
bool check(const char *word)
{
    // TODO
    int box = hash(word);

    char fin[strlen(word)];
    bool search = false;
    for (node *find = table[box]; find != NULL; find = find -> next)
    {        
        if (strcasecmp(find->word, word))
        {
            search = true;
        }        
    }                
}```

Comment: Скорее всего, у вас проблема не в том коде, который вы показываете, а в заполнении вашей хеш-таблицы. Тоже наверное нули финальные забываете вписать

Comment: Добавил функцию заполнения load().

Comment: Ну а что делает hash()?

Comment: Хеш берет первые три буквы без учета регистра, и по ним определяет в какой из связных списков сохранять слово.